# numpy mask array limiting the frequency of masked values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Starting from an array:

```
a = np.array([1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5])
```

and a filter:

```
m = np.array([1,5])
```

I am now building a mask with:

```
b = np.in1d(a,m)
```

that correctly returns:

```
array([ True,  True,  True, False, False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

I would need to limit the number of boolean `True`s for unique values to a maximum value of 2, so that 1 is masked only two times instead of three). The resulting mask would then appear (no matter the order of the first real `True` values):

```
array([ True,  True,  False, False, False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

or

```
array([ True,  False,  True, False, False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

or

```
array([ False,  True,  True, False, False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Ideally this is a kind of "random" masking over a limited frequency of values. So far I tried to random select the original unique elements in the array, but actually the mask select the `True` values no matter their frequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a generic case with unsorted input array, here's one approach based on [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
N = 2 # Parameter to decide how many duplicates are allowed

sortidx = a.argsort()
idx = np.searchsorted(a,m,sorter=sortidx)[:,None] + np.arange(N)
lim_counts = (a[:,None] == m).sum(0).clip(max=N)
idx_clipped = idx[lim_counts[:,None] > np.arange(N)]
out = np.in1d(np.arange(a.size),idx_clipped)[sortidx.argsort()]
```

Sample run -

```
In [37]: a
Out[37]: array([5, 1, 4, 2, 1, 3, 5, 1])

In [38]: m
Out[38]: [1, 2, 5]

In [39]: N
Out[39]: 2

In [40]: out
Out[40]: array([ True, True, False, True, True, False, True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Sorry is this limited to m of size 2? Is there a generic method for bigger sizes?

Comment: And actually changing m to, for instance, [1,2] leads to wrong results.

Comment: @FabioLamanna Yeah that was a bug indeed. Please check out the edits.